# How do i pass a route parameter value to both my header component and page content component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to pass a route param value to 2 components at the same time. The Header component as well as the body component. While the value goes to the body seamlessly the header doesn't receive any route param.

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <AppHeader />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} allowed={[]} />
          <Route exact path="/DetailPage/:id" component={DetailPage} />
          <Route exact path="/DetailPage/SubDetail/:id" component={SubDetailPage} />
        </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Here AppHeader is a common for all pages ie. `HomePage`, `DetailPage` and `SubDetailPage`.
When I'm in home page I enter the id that needs to be shown in the header for all pages and also it will be used in the body of DetailPage and SubDetailPage.

In home page I call this method inside a click event after capturing the id in a textfield:

```
navigateToDetailPage = idNumber => {
    this.props.history.push(`/DetailPage/${idNumber }`)
  }
```

This works perfectly and in the DetailPage body i can access this : `this.props.match.params.id`

But I need to pass the same to the AppHeader as well for showing the entered Id on the header. I can't figure out a way to access the value. Suggestions plz.

I expect to receive the same id into both AppHeader , DetailPage , SubDetailPage.

Comment: Maby in your case you should use reducer, where you will have state "idNumber". With redux saga you can change this data in BrowserRouter container.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

In `HomePage` when you enter the `id`, you can store it in `localStorage`,

```
localStorage.setItem('id',id);
```

Now you can access `id` from `localStorage` anywhere in the app,

```
navigateToDetailPage = () => {
    let idNumber = localStorage.getItem('id');
    this.props.history.push(`/DetailPage/${idNumber}`)
}
```

Comment: The idea is if i give someone the link like ```http://localhost:3000/detailPage/1144``` it should work. Is there no better way than storage like using routing itself ?

Comment: First thing is, your `localhost` link will not work on any other system. You need to host your code on server and provide the server link.